# Is web service is better than the regular query method?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a desktop application. we need to install in client pc and connect the database to remote server. which method is better to connect database (for speed and performance).
1. Normal query method (mention the server name in connection string).
2. Create a web service and get the data in xml or json format.

Comment: Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages. Which is better is dependent of the details and context (you could weight some factors more heavily than others would). Thus this is unanswerable objectively.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions will bring positive and negative points.

**Direct query to server** -> imply that your client software knows the Database schema. If you change the Database schema, you need to test its integration in the client app.

**Web service** ->  a limited API allows your Database to be only known by its data web service. The client app only knows about the small web service API. When the Database evolves, you have a very low chance to negatively impact the client code.

From an architectural point of view, it is encouraged to limit the size of contracts between 2 pieces of technology.

From a development cost point of view, creating and maintaining such a service has a cost and introduces maybe the need of a new set of technical skill set in your team.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirement, budget and time constraint.

If there is any possibility that this desktop software would be later extended to Mobile App and other platforms, then go for Creating web services preferably with JSON.

Keeping data access layer in Client Desktop Application saves a little development time, but makes testing, re usability and maintenance harder.

Also, the trend is to use SOA, thus I'd always prefer creating Web Services. Its secure, reusable and very friendly for future modification to project.